# How to change spaces between items in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing

Is it possible to get it without using package `titletoc`? I'm using special chapter style which doesn't work with this package.

Comment: And the `tocloft` package is an option?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Perhaps provide further information, such as you preamble or even better a small compilable example with your class, packages and settings.

Comment: Just for future reference: I've found that setting `\parskip` can be useful. E.g. `\parskip=1em` for large spacing or `\parskip=0em` for compact spacing, it works for me in the article document class.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There are so many options... without further information, one possible option would be to use the [`setspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package and one of its commands of environments; for example,

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\doublespacing
\tableofcontents
\singlespacing

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section Two One}
\section{Test Section Two Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This approach will increase evenly the space between all sectional units. The following three options allow you to control separately the spacing for each group of sectional units.

Another option would be to use the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package and redefine the `\cftXafterpnum` family of commands:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip10pt}
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip15pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section Two One}
\section{Test Section Two Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Yet another option, this time using the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch the sectional units commands to add vertical space to the ToC:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\chapter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{15\p@}}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\section}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{5\p@}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One One}
\section{Test Section One Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\section{Test Section Two One}
\section{Test Section Two Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A fourth option not requiring any packages would be to redefine the `\chapter` and `\section` commands as implemented in the used document class to add the vertical space to the ToC; an example with `report`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{5\p@}}%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\renewcommand\section{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20\p@}}%
  \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section Two}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 55):

While the other suggestions so far allow increasing the line spacing of the Table of Contents, it seems they don't allow decreasing it, for example to fit a ToC on one page.

A simple

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.75}\normalsize
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\normalsize
```

will allow setting any line spacing.

It might be necessary to find out what your baselinestretch size is by default as the style seems to set this.

Comment: negative value of -10pt decreased the spacing for me `\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip-10pt}`

Comment: This answer was perfect for me! I've been having package incompatibility issues with most of the recommended TOC pages, and the TOC was dangling by one line to create an extra page. Using `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.9975}\normalsize` instead of `0.7` was enough to get rid of the extra page. Thank you so much!

Comment: This can also be used to increase the spacing, it appears to be the easiest solution!

Answer (score 21):

Using [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/), you can also add the following in your preamble to add spacing *before* a section entry:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{6pt}
```

This complements [Gonzalo's Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56550/31770) in where he shows how to add spacing *after* a section entry: that can be undesirable in case you have subsections following a section.  The [tocloft's manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf) has many other options that can be used to manipulate other types of entries in the TOC.

Comment: I found this to be the most flexible solution. Include \setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{6pt} and \setlength{\cftbeforesubsubsecskip}{6pt} to get custom spacing between sub- and subsub- sections in the toc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to do it ! However, you need load this package

```
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{spacing}{4}
\tableofcontents 
\end{spacing}
```

Found this technique here : https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7701

Answer (score 0):

Another global solution for **reducing** spacing, for cases where kjyv's local solution didn't work or caused trouble with line spacing in general is

```
\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\\ \vspace{-20pt}}
```

which worked for me while

```
\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip-10pt}
```

didn't do anything.

Comment: Note that this answer presumes that the `tocloft` package is used.