# How to change the spacing for chapters which are not numbered

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

I would like to make a custom TOC so that:

  Introduction

  I.CHAPTER

  II. CHAPTER
    1. Section
    2. Section

  III. CHAPTER

  List of figures

  List of tables

  Notes

The main idea is that chapters without numbers have different spacing (before or after) between other chapters. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56550/31058).

Answer (score 1):

You can insert content into the ToC using `\addcontentsline{<toc>}{<section>}{<title>}` and `\addtocontents{<toc>}{<stuff>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\inserttocgap}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{2\baselineskip}}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}\inserttocgap
\section{A section}
\section{Another section}
\inserttocgap
\section*{An unnumbered section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{An unnumbered section}
\end{document}
```

The above works for `article`, but can be updated to work for `book` or `report` that defines `\chapter`. Just use

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{<title>}
```

`\inserttocgap` inserts a `2\baselineskip` gap. In order to survive writing to the ToC (and expansion), `\protect` it.