# How to remove spaces between the items of table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, document-classes, article, abstract

I have compiled the following document.

[image]

My attempt is as follows:

```
\documentclass[oneside, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\sectionfont{\centering}


\newcommand{\myRed}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\myGreen}[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
\newcommand{\myBlue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}



\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{remarks}{Remarks}[section]


\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\scshape\filcenter}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}
  

\renewcommand*\contentsname{\hfill Contents \hfill}     

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=red,
    urlcolor=blue
}
%\singlespacing


\begin{document}
\font\myfont=cmr12 at 14pt

\title{\textbf{\myfont ARTICLE NAME}}

\author{\footnotesize MY NAME }
\date{}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
We will prove the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{center}
    \tableofcontents
\end{center}


\section{Introduction}
jhuhrc 
\section{Topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$}
Hi, this is toplogy
\section{Surfaces}
\section{Classification of Surfaces}
\end{document}
```

I want to create the fonts of abstract and contents as the sections (e.g. Introduction, Surfaces etc.). Also, I cannot able the vertical distance between the items and boldness of table of contents.

Please help me.

Comment: Perhaps [line spacing - How to change spaces between items in Table of Contents - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56546/how-to-change-spaces-between-items-in-table-of-contents?rq=1)

Comment: Unrelated, but you should try and avoid loading same packages multiple times (enumitem, for example, here). A clean preamble is always a good thing to start with.

Comment: don't use primitive font command such as `\font\myfont=cmr12 at 14pt` in latex, you can choose 14pt with `\Large`  as you have it you have 14pt font on a 13.6pt baseline spacing which is not achievable so you will have uneven and inconsistent linespacing throughout the document.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have `\usepackage{tocloft}` in your preamble but you do not use it in the MWE.

In your document before `\tableofcontent` insert (from the `tocloft` package)

```
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt}
```

to get the normal text spacing between the `section` entries. A negative length will move the section entries even closer together and a positive length will move them further apart.

You list a lot of packages in your MWE. Do you really need them all in your real document?